# Django url error in template with password_change view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-generic-views

I am using Django `1.2.3-3+squeeze1` with Debian squeeze.

I am trying to use the Django password change view in my application
corresponding to `django.contrib.auth.views.password_change`. This
looks like it should be straightforward, but I have been having
problems.

For simplicity and completeness, I will point to my application files
online. The application is [bixfile](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile). The
corresponding Django project is [bixproj](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixproj).

The relevant line in url.py is
https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/49bcbab3a7be/urls.py#cl-65,
namely

```
url(r'^password_change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'post_change_redirect':reverse('top_folders')}, name="password_change"),
```

This breaks any template in which it is used. Currently, I'm only
using it at line
https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/templates/calgb_base.html#cl-21
of the template calgb_base.html, which is included in a bunch of
templates including the top level index view, corresponding to the
template
https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/templates/index.html. The
line in calgb_base.html is

```
<li><a class="side" href="{% url password_change %}">Password Change</a></li>
```

When I navigate to the top `index` view corresponding to
https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/urls.py#cl-16
and
https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/views.py#cl-203
I see an error, beginning with

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'password_change'
with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I doubt the full traceback is useful, but I have pasted it at
http://paste.lisp.org/display/122996.

This error is reproducible with both Apache 2.2 and mod-wsgi, as well
as the builtin Django test server (see below).

If I go directly the the /password_change/ relative url, I see the
password change form as expected.

The weird thing is that all the tests I have written to test this
pass, and produce the expected result. See for example
[testIndexUrl](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/tests.py#cl-313)
,
[testIndexView](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/tests.py#cl-317)
and
[test_password_change_url](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile/src/71de33d01f43/tests.py#cl-1029).

You can run the tests from the `bixproj` directory with

```
python manage.py test
```

If you want to try to reproduce this error it is comparatively easy.

First download the project (`bixproj`) and application repositories
(`bixfile`). So

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/faheem/bixproj
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/faheem/bixfile
```

Then make sure bixfile is in the Python path. Change DATABASES to use
sqlite. Then change

```
LOGIN_URL = '/'+BIXFILE_NAME+'/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/'+BIXFILE_NAME+'/'
```

to

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/'
```

Then running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

in the `bixproj` directory on a local machine and going to the default url
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/` should display the error.

I expect I can produce a minimal example showing the error if
necessary, but I'm really hoping this error is obvious and I don't
have to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bixfiles.urls` uses `reverse`. This is not possible, because the urls have not been loaded when `reverse` is called.

Django 1.4 will have a [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy) feature that will solve this problem.

In the meantime, you can:

1. Implement `reverse_lazy` in your project (see [changeset 16121](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/16121)).
2. Hardcode the urls instead of using reverse

Comment: @Alasdair: I tried both `reverse_lazy` and hardcoding the 'post_change_redirect' argument instead of using `reverse`, as you suggested. Unfortunately, neither of these works. I get exactly the same error as before. Note I am using `reverse` in a very similar fashion in `urls.py` just above the problematic entry with no problems. Did you test this proposed fix?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. When I replaced **all** of the reversed urls in `bixfiles.urls.py` with `'/'`, the index page worked for me.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment -- I believe the problem is not `reverse` in the url patter for the index page, it is using `reverse` in **any** of your url patterns. Have you tried removing reverse from your urls completely? It worked for me.

Comment: @Alasdair: I replaced `reverse everywhere with `reverse_lazy`, per the link you posted. To define `reverse_lazy` I did `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,
from django.utils.functional import lazy,
reverse_lazy = lazy(reverse, str)`. It works, so it looks like that really was the problem. Thanks very much for your assistance with this.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the error message is so unhelpful, and gives
 no clue to the problem. Cannot something be done about this? Also,
 the documentation of 1.2 gives no hint that `reverse` is problematic, and can cause difficult to trace failures. If reverse_lazy solves the problem, why not make it the default?

Comment: I'm glad you've got it working. I agree it's a nasty gotcha. It's not immediately obvious that the url did not match because you used reverse in the urls patterns. I have suggested on the [django developers](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers) group that we add an extra example to the lazy_reverse documentation about using it in url patterns.